# How do I Render Tiles at different sizes?

Tags: java, 2d, tile

so I have my Tile class:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class Tile {

    public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];
    public static Tile airTile = new AirTile(0);
    public static Tile grassTile = new GrassTile(1);
    public static Tile dirtTile = new DirtTile(2);
    public static Tile rockTile = new RockTile(3);
    //public static Tile anvilTile = new AnvilTile(50);


    public static int w, h;
    public static final int TILE_WIDTH = 64, TILE_HEIGHT = 64;

    private BufferedImage texture;
    protected final int id;

    public Tile(BufferedImage texture, int id, int w, int  h){
        this.texture = texture;
        this.id = id;
        this.h = h;
        this.w = w;

        tiles[id] = this;

    }

    public void tick(){

    }

    public void render(Graphics g, int x, int y){
        g.drawImage(texture, x, y, w, h, null);
    }

    public boolean isSolid(){
        return false;

    }



    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return w;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return h;
    }
    }
```

and here is an example DirtTile class

```
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

 public class DirtTile extends Tile{

public DirtTile(int id) {
    super(Assets.dirt, id, 64, 64);

}

@Override
public boolean isSolid(){
    return false;
}

}
```

As you can see my DirtTile class is giving my Tile class it's width and height, however I wanted to try and make a wider tile (128 x 64):

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class AnvilTile extends Tile{

public AnvilTile(int id) {
    super(Assets.anvil, id, 128, 64);

}
```

}

Doing this sets every Tile to be 128px wide, I only want the AnvilTile class to be 128px wide, so basically i will have to make changes to the Render method in my Tile class, however I don't know how to do this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is this line `public static int w, h;`. Hint: it is related to the use of the `static` keyword. - Btw, I'd assume your editor would warn you about that in your constructor.

Comment: What a silly mistake, thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `w` and `h` fields are static and these values are shared across all `Tile` instances. So when you create a new `AnvilTile` object, the call to `super` sets the `w` and `h` fields across all instances to 128 and 64 respectively.

Remove the `static` modifier to achieve your desired result. Now the fields are instance variables, meaning that each `Tile` instance has its own values for `w` and `h`.